# Android: Append new data to already drawn ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

so in short:
I have chat server online which uses sockets, so when user types something in chat - it sends a message to all currently connected clients.
In web browser I am using append javascript to add messages to chat window.

In Android I plan to use ListView ( I don't see any alternative ), so as user enters the chat - app loads all previous messages into ListView and creates it.

Now question is:
Is it possible to append/add data to ListViews bottom without redrawing whole ListView? I want message arrival to be invisible to user, I don't want whole window to refresh.

Is it possible? Using fragments by the way.

Answer (score 3):

of course possible. You just add your New Arrived data into your `Array` or `ArrayList` that you passed in your `Adapter` and called

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

look at another post [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Comment: Wouldn't closing as duplicate be better ?

Comment: @2Dee Yaa. Off course budy!!!!

Comment: @MD if you know this question is duplicate then why are you answering a question.. Or you must have to do comment ...